Prove that $\sup⁡(A\cup B)=\max\{\sup⁡(A),\sup⁡(B)\}$
I want to prove $\sup⁡(A\cup B)=\max\{\sup⁡(A),\sup⁡(B)\}$, where $A,B\subset \mathbb R$ are non-empty and bounded sets from above. I have reviewed similar questions and answers, but I intended to prove directly using the following definition of least upper bound:
$\sup ( A) \in \mathbb R$ and $A\subseteq \mathbb R$ if

$\forall a\in A$, $a \leq \sup( A)$,
$\forall \varepsilon >0$, $\exists b \in A$ such that $\sup( A)-\varepsilon<b$.

Here's my proof:

We know $A \cup B=\{x \mid x\in A \text{ or }x\in B \} $,
$\forall a \in A$, $a \leq \sup⁡(A) $ and $\forall b \in B$, $b \leq \sup⁡(B) $, thus $\forall a \in A$ and $\forall b \in B$, $a,b\leq \max\{\sup⁡(A),\sup⁡(B)\}$.
$\forall \varepsilon>0 $, $\exists k_A \in A$ s.t. $\sup( A)-\varepsilon  <k_A$ and $\exists k_B \in B$ s.t. $\sup( B)-\varepsilon  <k_B$. $k_A\in A\cup B$, and $\sup(A)\geq \sup(B)$ implies $\sup(A)-\varepsilon=\max\{\sup⁡(A),\sup⁡(B)\}-\varepsilon <k_A$. After considering vice versa, we can write, $\exists k\in A\cup B$, $\max\{\sup⁡(A),\sup⁡(B)\}-\varepsilon<k$.

Since both properties are satisfied, we can conclude that $\sup⁡(A\cup B)=\max\{\sup⁡(A),\sup⁡(B)\}$.
Question: Is this proof correct? I have some bad feelings regarding my 3rd argument. Thank you!

Indeed, thanks! @Zima

Looks good to me! As a small recommendation, in an argument like this it's sometimes clearer to assume wlog that $\sup A \geq \sup B$

You are right to have "bad feelings regarding 3rd argument". Your "let $k\in A\cup B$" is really unclear. Who is this $k$? Is it $k_A$? or $k_B$? or someone else? Instead, assuming $\sup A\ge\sup B$, choose $k=k_A$.

@JMP The question is different. OP is asking for a proof verification.

@AnneBauval I used (or at least intended) the $k$'s as the elements that slip in between supremums and their $\varepsilon$ neighbourhoods. But does using a distinct variable solve the ambiguity?

"Let $k\in A\cup B$. Then, $\sup(A)\geq \sup(B)$ implies $\sup(A)-\varepsilon <k$" is false. "$k_A\in A\cup B$, and $\sup(A)\geq \sup(B)$ implies $\max{\sup⁡(A),\sup⁡(B)}-\varepsilon <k_A$" is true. "After considering vice versa, we can write" $\exists k\in A\cup B,;\max{\sup⁡(A),\sup⁡(B)}-\varepsilon<k$.

Your proof will then become ok, but only if $A,B$ are non-empty and bounded from above. For other proofs, see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/921975 provided by JMP, and the many posts linked to it.

@AnneBauval Aha... Thanks! I thought I said $\exists k\in A \cup B $. I will edit that. I see that other proofs use the relation $\sup(A)\leq\sup(A\cup B)$. I tried to prove directly from the definition of sup. I don't know if there is any value in it but yeah.

More generally, the supremum of any union is the supremum of the suprema (i.e., $\sup(\bigcup_{i \in I} A_i)=\sup({\sup(A_i)}_{i \in I})$).

You have to start with the fact that both $A$ and $B$ are bounded. Then you should show that $A\cup B$ is bounded and then proceed to the result.

@AnneBauval I hope it is correct now.

Yes, this was verbatim my advice, provided (as simultaneoulsy commented) that $A,B$ are non-empty and bounded from above (then, so will be $A\cup B$, as you already showed).

Your proof looks fine after following the suggestions in the comments. But you may consider writing it in plain English to make it easier to understand.
Let $A, B \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ be bounded from above; i.e., there is some $x \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $a < x$ for all $a \in A$ and some $y \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $b < y$ for all $b \in B$. Let $C = A \cup B$.
The set $C$ must be bounded from above: take $z = \max\{a, b\} \in \mathbb{R}$; for any $c \in C$, if $c \in A$, then $c < x \le z$ and if $c \in B$, then $c < y \le z$.
Denote $m = \max\{\sup A, \sup B\}$; we want to show that $m = \sup C$. Then (1) $m$ needs to be an upper bound of $C$, and (2) $m$ cannot be larger than any upper bound of $C$ (equivalent to the second part of your definition).
To show (1) is easy: let $c \in C$ be arbitrary. If $c \in A$, then $c \le \sup A \le m$ and if $c \in B$, then $c \le \sup B \le m$. Either way, $c \le m$, as desired.
To show (2), suppose for the sake of contradiction that there is some $n < m$ that is an upper bound of $C$. Then $n < \sup A$ or $n < \sup B$. In the former case, there is some $a \in A$ such that $a > n$; since $a \in C$, this contradicts the fact that $n$ is an upper bound of $C$. A similar argument applies if $n < \sup B$. Therefore, $m$ must be the smallest upper bound of $C$, completing the proof.

Option:
$1)A \subset (A\cup B)$, and
$B\subset (A\cup B),$ hence
$\sup (A) \le \sup (A\cup B)$,
and
$\sup (B) \le \sup (A\cup B) $.
Thus
$\max ${$\sup (A) , \sup (B) $} $\le \sup (A\cup B).$
$2)a\le \max ${$\sup (A) , \sup (B) $}, and 
$b\le \max ${$\sup (A) ,\sup (B) $},
Let $c \in (A \cup B),$ then 
$c \le \max ${$\sup (A), \sup (B)$}, i e.
$\max ${$\sup(A),\sup (B) $} 
is an upper bound for $c \in (A\cup B) $.
Since $\sup (A\cup B)$ is the least upper bound for {$c$}, we have
$\sup (A \cup B)$ 
$\le \max ${$\sup (A), \sup (B)$},
and we are done.

Thanks for your proof! I am hesitant to use $\sup(A) \leq \sup(A \cup B)$ in proving this property because it seems to rely on a property of equal level. (I don't know if that makes sense). That is why I preferred to prove it directly from the definition of $\sup$ only.

@Ba_nanza. Property of equal level I am not familiar with this. Does it  make sense if you have $ D \subset E$ then sup (D) $\le$ sup (E) ?

Sure, that makes sense. Although this is a very elementary proof and property, the proof you use requires another relation that seems to need the property "$A \subset B \Rightarrow \sup(A) \leq \sup(B)$," which also needs a proof of similar complexity to the one we are trying to make. That is why I aimed to use a proof that relies only on even more primitive relations (in this case, only the definitions of $\sup$).

That is fine, you proved it.
