# $\emptyset$ does not have a supremum.

Tags: real-analysis, supremum-and-infimum

Ghorpade-Limaye, A couse in Calculus and Real Analysis, p.5) says that $\emptyset$ does not have a supremum but there is not any explanation.

My question is: Why?

Comment: It's vacuous a supremum is a number **for all** $x\in S$ so that [...], and the least of all such numbers. But every number is an upper bound, so the supremum is not a number.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/472532/9464

Comment: See [Infimum and supremum of the empty set](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/432295) and other posts [linked there](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/432295).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Infimum and supremum of the empty set](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/432295/infimum-and-supremum-of-the-empty-set)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, a supremum of a set $A$ is a number $a$ such that

- $a$ is $\ge$ every element of $A$ (such an $a$ is called an *upper bound* of $A$), and
- $a$ is $\le$ any number $b$ with the previous property.

Now, here's the problem:

> What *isn't* an upper bound of the empty set?

For example, $4$ is an upper bound of $\emptyset$. Why? Well, $4$ is $\ge$ every element of the emptyset. You don't believe me? OK, find me an element of the emptyset which is not $\le 4$.

(Similarly, every element of the emptyset is an elephant.)

So the problem is that every real number is an upper bound of $\emptyset$. But there is no least real number, so the emptyset doesn't have a least upper bound - that is, the emptyset has no supremum.

Comment: Yes. Thanks....

Answer (score 3):

Every real number is an upper bound for $\emptyset$. So there is no smallest real number. The same reasoning applies for the infimum. What is interesting, however, is that you can use this reasoning to find $\sup\emptyset = -\infty$ and $\inf\emptyset = \infty$ in the extended reals.

Comment: I could'nt believe that **sup** $\emptyset = -\infty$ and vice versa.

Comment: Yeah it is definitely counter-intuitive, but let's tackle the supremum. Every real number is an upper bound for $\emptyset$. This means $\sup\emptyset \le x$ for all $x \in\Bbb{R}$. But the only number that satisfies this is $-\infty$.

Comment: Definition of SUP says that Let $S$ be a subset of $\mathbb{R}$. An element $M\in\mathbb{R}$ is called a *supremem* of the set $S$ if bla bla...  So, $-\infty$ or $\infty$ is not a element.

Comment: i.e., $M$ could not equal to $-\infty$ or $\infty$.

Comment: I could not believe still.

Comment: That is the analysis definition of supremum. In general all you need is a partially ordered set. i.e. Let $(P,\le)$ be a partially ordered set, then define supremum in the obvious way.

Comment: What is $-\infty$ mean? Is it a number or a real number or an element? NO! So, How it satisfy $-\infty$?

Comment: $-\infty$ is the smallest element in the ordered set $\overline{\mathbb{R}}$. In fact we could extend this result. Let $(P,\le)$ be any partially ordered set with a smallest element $\alpha$. Then $\sup\emptyset = \alpha$.

Comment: What is $\overline {\mathbb{R} }$ mean?

Comment: So, $-\infty$ could not be an element since $-\infty$ is not an element but you says that $-\infty$ is the smallest ''element'' in order set....

Comment: $\overline{\mathbb{R}} = \mathbb{R}\cup\{-\infty, \infty\}$ So basically you just take $\mathbb{R}$ and give it a largest and smallest element. This is known as the extended reals

Comment: Okey, thanks...

Comment: In particular, the extended reals form a complete lattice.

Answer (score 2):

Every real number is an upper bound of $\emptyset$. That is to say, the set of all upper bounds of $\emptyset$ is $\Bbb{R}$, which has no least element.

Answer (score 0):

The supremum is the least upper bound. What's an upper bound of $\emptyset$? It is $a\in\mathbb R$ such that $x\leq a$ for all $x\in \emptyset$. Since no such $x$ exists, either you interpret that all $a$ are upper bounds, so there is no least upper bound, or that no $a$ is an upper bound, in which case there is no least upper bound either.