# What is wrong with the following function

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

The following apparently defines a function, but there is something wrong with it which I am struggling to find:

$$m:\mathcal P(\{1,2,3,\dots,100\})\to\{1,2,3,\dots,100\}$$
$$m(A) =\text{the smallest element of }A$$

Is it the fact that when the domain is the empty set, the codomain would have to be 0, which is not actually inlcuded in the codomain? Am I right to assume that the smallest element of the empty set is 0?

Comment: The empty set has no elements, so it isn't true that the smallest element is $0$, or anything else.  The problem is that the function is not defined at $\emptyset$.  (You are misusing the terms "domain" and "codomain."  These refer to the entire set, not individual elements.)

Comment: [Related](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/432295/infimum-and-supremum-of-the-empty-set).  The infimum of an empty set is usually $+\infty$.  That said, minimums and infimums, although related, are not identical terms.  Minimums must be elements of the set in question.

Comment: @saulspatz So how would I define it at ∅? Would i have to inlcude ∅ in the domain?

Comment: @kafo $\emptyset$ *is* in the domain.  The empty set *is* an element of $\mathcal{P}(\{1,2,\dots,100\})$.  The minimum of $\emptyset$ doesn't exist and is undefined.  Related, the infimum of $\emptyset$, namely $\infty$, is not an element of the codomain.  Those are the problem.  You could get around this by rewording $m$ to be infimum instead of minimum and include $+\infty$ in the codomain, you could reword $m$ to say explicitly that $m$ acts on $\emptyset$ in a specific way... for instance that $m(\emptyset)$ is defined to equal $42$... or you could remove $\emptyset$ from the domain.

Comment: While you could if you insist include $0$ in the codomain and explicitly define $m$ to be the minimum of a set for non-empty sets in the domain and $0$ for the empty set, this is ill-advised as it loses several of the nice properties of $m$ unless you bend over backwards trying to fix all the problems.  For instance, if it weren't for the empty set we would have that $m(A\cup B) = m(\{m(A),m(B)\})$.  Similarly, ignoring the empty set we have $m(A\cup B)\leq m(A)$.  Letting $m(\emptyset)$ be smaller than the other outputs rather than larger breaks this.

Answer (score 4):

The function is indeed ill-defined, for "the smallest element of $A$, $m(A)$" has no meaning if $A=\varnothing$. It is nonsense to define $m(\varnothing)=0$ without adding $0$ to the codomain set first.