# What is the probability that a random variable is smaller than null?

Tags: probability

I want to show that the probability that a random variable $X$ is smaller than a set of variables $C=\{C_1,C_2,...\}$ is equal to $a$. I use notation $X<C$ to show that $X$ is smaller than all $C$s. But set $C$ may be empty. How should I handle situation $P(X<C)$ when $C$ is empty? What is the right notation for it? Can I write $P(X<\emptyset)=1$?

Comment: What is the interpretation of $X<C$ to begin with?

Comment: I use notation $X<C$ to show that $X$ is smaller than all $C$s

Comment: In that case, I would use $X<\inf C$ and then https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/432295/infimum-and-supremum-of-the-empty-set#:~:text=If%20we%20consider%20subsets%20of,the%20empty%20set%20is%20%E2%88%92%E2%88%9E.

Comment: @YJT Thank you, can you explain in more detail?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the clarification in the comments:

You compare $X$ to all the elements of $C$, and the event $X<C$ in your notation is actually $X<\inf C$ in the standard one.
(you compare random variables with numbers, not sets.)

Thus, if $C=\emptyset$ there is no problem: $\inf \emptyset=\infty$ [(explanation)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/432295/infimum-and-supremum-of-the-empty-set#:%7E:text=If%20we%20consider%20subsets%20of,the%20empty%20set%20is%20%E2%88%92%E2%88%9E) and thus $\Pr(X<\inf \emptyset)=1$.
If you want to keep your notation, I guess there is no problem writing $X<\emptyset$ but it should be clearly defined in your text as it is not standard nor common.

Comment: Thank you very much for your clear answer

Comment: If $C=\{0,1\}$ then $\inf C=0$ and $\sup C=1$. To be smaller than all the elements, it should be smaller than the $\inf$ (by definition - inf is the highest lower bound).